# Check if list of managers contains an employee in any of its manager's lists of employees that's also a manager

Tags: c#, list, recursion

I get a SOAP response that looks something like this:

```
<Record>
    <EmployeeId>1</EmployeeId>
    <ManagerId>5</ManagerId>
</Record>
<Record>
    <EmployeeId>9</EmployeeId>
    <ManagerId>7</ManagerId>
</Record>
```

I create a Manager class that has the following properties:

```
class Manager
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<int> Employees { get; set; }
    }
```

And I loop through the records in the response to fill a List of Manager with it:

```
List<Manager> managers = new List<Manager>();

foreach (Record record in records)
{
    Manager manager = managers.Find(m => m.Id == ManagerId);

    if (manager == null)
    {
            manager = new Manager
            {
                Id = ManagerId,
                Employees = new List<int>
                {
                    EmployeeId
                },
            };
            managers.Add(manager);
    }

    else
    {
        if (!manager.Employees.Contains(EmployeeId))
            {
                manager.Employees.Add(EmployeeId);
            }
    }
}
```

Question Is If a manager has another manager in its list of employees I need to add the second manager's employees to the first manager's list of employees, and if any of those employees are also managers I need to add them as well, this goes on multiple levels deep.

I imagine that this would require some kind of recursion, Everything I've tried becomes overly complex and inefficient very fast.

Should I use something else instead of a list of objects with lists within them?
Or Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're checking to see if the list of employees contains the employee before adding it (i.e. are you getting duplicate records from the service)?

Comment: @theMayer Yes, there are duplicate records, records of multiple managers with the same employee and employees with themselves as managers.

Comment: Ok, so writing the cleanup logic would mean that you’d have to define what that is. An employee with self as manager is going to result in an endless loop unless you deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your performance loss is the following line:

`Manager manager = managers.Find(m => m.Id == ManagerId);`

This line is called once for every employee in the list, and its implementation is to loop through and return the first match. Instead, you need to set up a `Dictionary<int, Manager>` to contain your records. Assuming there are no duplicate records (i.e. records where the `Id` property is the same), then the following would work:

```
public class Manager
{
    public readonly int ManagerId;
    public readonly int EmployeeId;
    public readonly List<int> Employees = new List<int>();

    public Manager(int employeeId, int managerId) {
        this.ManagerId = managerId;
        this.EmployeeId = employeeId;
    }
}
```

---

```
var dict = records.Select(o => new Manager(o.EmployeeId, o.ManagerId))
                  .ToDictionary(o => o.EmployeeId);
foreach (var record in records)
{
    Manager manager;
    dict.TryGetValue(record.ManagerId, out manager);
    // recursively walk up the tree and add the record to each parent, etc.
    while (manager != null) {
        manager.Employees.Add(record.EmployeeId);
        dict.TryGetValue(manager.ManagerId, out manager);
    }
}
```

Note that I would update the constructor for `Manager` to accept the employee and manager Ids and also initialize the list.

Comment: Note I haven't tested this - you can do that. Due to how int behaves (i.e. value is never null), you might run into some oddities where an employee doesn't have a manager (top level root).

Comment: That's a very elegant solution. If there were no duplicate records it would work perfectly as is. Still, I think I should be able to adapt it to what I need, thank you very much!

Comment: Duplicates are best eliminated by using a hash set instead of a list.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The other issue would be the same employee having multiple records for different managers when creating the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in xml linq in one instruction using a dictionary :

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = doc.Descendants("Record")
                .GroupBy(x => (int)x.Element("ManagerId"), y => (int)y.Element("EmployeeId"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OPs want a list of employees for each manages which is what I provided.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for your answer, it's much better than what I had. In addition to what you provided, what I was asking for is a way to recursively check if the employees of a manager are also managers and if so, add their employees to the parent manager.